# Tile padding with content is out of line

Tags: html, css

I'm working on a simple tile view using HTML and CSS. It's working OK and without any serious content, also looks OK, but if I add any images or the like, it instantly makes it look rubbish (the site can be found [here](http://roconnor.gitlab.io)) What am I doing wrong? I've had a look at padding and there isn't anything in that space!

My code is below:

```css
ul.tiles {
    max-width: 620px;
    height: auto;
}

ul.tiles li {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background: #FAFAFA;
    z-index: 0;
    margin: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
    transition: all .15s ease-in-out;
    box-shadow: 0 2.5px 5px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.2);
}

ul.tiles li * {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

ul.tiles li:hover {
    background: #FAFAFA;
    z-index: 100;
    transform: scale(1.0,1.0);
    box-shadow: 0 5px 10px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.2);
}
```

```html
<div class="row" style="">
    <div class="col-md-9">
        <ul class="tiles">
            <li><img src="//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png" /></li>
            <li><img src="//pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/602729491916435458/hSu0UjMC.jpg" /></li>
            <li><a href="#">Topic 3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Topic 4</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't understand the problem. What exactly do you want?

Comment: @Gofilord laligi has sorted it but the tiles were out of line when they had images in them. If you looked at the link it was broken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add `vertical-align:top`

```
ul.tiles li {
    background: #fafafa none repeat scroll 0 0;
    box-shadow: 0 2.5px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    display: inline-block;
    height: 200px;
    margin: 5px;
    position: relative;
    transition: all 0.15s ease-in-out 0s;
    vertical-align: top;/*add this property*/
    width: 200px;
    z-index: 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this is brilliant! I can't accept right now but I will as soon as possible

Answer (score 1):

```
ul.tiles {
  max-width: 620px;
  height: auto;
}
```

try making the height fixed